# postgres column with nulll values and filtering with "!="

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query:

```
select * from students where status != 4.
```

I am not getting rows with status null.

Shouldn't it return all the rows where status is not 4 - including rows with null status values?

I can get what I need by following query.

```
select * from students where status != 4 or status is null
```

Comment: See the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-logical.html - in particularly the truth table there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:
    IS DISTINCT FROM

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE status IS DISTINCT FROM 4;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html

Answer (score 2):

SQL's understanding of `NULL` is ["three-valued"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL). Think of `NULL` as `UNKNOWN`. So, in other words:

```
UNKNOWN  = 4 yields      UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN != 4 yields also UNKNOWN
```

In other words, if a student has `status is null`, then it is "unknown" whether that status is different from 4

Answer (score 0):

Any comparison using normal comparison operators with null is never true, except for the two special IS NULL and IS NOT NULL comparisons.

Comment: And the other two special comparison operators IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (with their irritating backwards logic).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit disturbing but `null` is not a value and r[equires](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) its specific operator `is`.